Why are vector embeddings not stored in Weaviate when building with ragstack-ai-langflow?
I have created a Vector Store RAG project in ragstack-ai-langflow. In this project, I am using Weaviate as the vector store database. I have provided the following inputs for the component:

Weaviate URL: http://localhost:8080/
Index name: "My_Index"
Input: (added the input component file and attached the file component as an input)
Embedding: OpenAI Embedding

The component builds successfully, but when I check the Weaviate database, there are no objects created.
I couldn't find what the issue was.
It built the component but not storing the data.I need
Can someone help me resolve this issue?

I'm not sure which document you're following but it seems you missed some critical information so let me provide some background.
RAGStack is a curated stack of open-source software from DataStax which in our opinion is the best choice of OSS packages for building production-ready RAG applications using Astra DB or Apache Cassandra® as the vector store.
The ragstack-ai-langflow package is the curated set of dependencies for using Langflow. At the time of writing, it only works with Astra DB but support for Cassandra, DataStax Enterprise and other DataStax software will be added very soon.
For full disclosure, I am both an Apache Cassandra committer and DataStax employee. Cheers!

Thank you, Erik, for the quick response. I understand your point. I need one more clarification. In the Langflow UI, there are options like Weaviate, Redis, Chroma, etc. under Vector Store. Are you saying that those are not working now? Should we use Astra or Cassandra for the vector store?

Correct. The open-source Langflow can connect to other vector stores but although ragstack-ai-langflow is based on open-source Langflow, RAGStack only works with Astra DB and Cassandra distributions. Cheers!

Thanks a lot, Erik for the Clarification :)
